# Get YouTube Videos from channel VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, youtube

How to get the videos in Listview with all the video details like views title author description dislikes likes favorites tags

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Developer's Guide: .NET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet)

The YouTube Data API allows client applications to retrieve and update YouTube content in the form of Google Data API feeds. Your client application can use the YouTube Data API to fetch video feeds, comments, responses, and playlists, as well as query for videos that match particular criteria. You can also use the API to make authenticated requests to modify this information and to upload new video content to the site.

**Retrieving standard feeds: Videos uploaded by a specific user**

For each YouTube user, the YouTube Data API defines a video feed that lists the videos that the user has uploaded. The video feed for a user's uploaded videos can be retrieved from the following URL:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads
```

You can also retrieve a specific entry for an uploaded video by sending an API request to the following URL:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads/VIDEO_ID
```

The following code demonstrates how to retrieve a feed of videos uploaded by a particular user:

```
Uri uri = 
  new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads");
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(uri); 
printVideoFeed(videoFeed);
```

In the feed URL, you can use the string default instead of a username to retrieve the videos uploaded by the currently authenticated user. In that case, you would retrieve the feed located at http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads.

In addition, when you retrieve the uploaded videos feed or a specific entry from that feed for the currently authenticated user, the feed entries (or the single entry) will be editable using the client library code. See the Identifying_Editable_Video_Entries section for more details.

Comment: Can you show me a simple code to retrieve a videos from channel to listview